# What's the point in leveling dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

What is the benefit of leveling up the dwellers?

It doesn't seem to give any benefit, in fact it is detrimental as higher level dwellers cost more caps to revive.

The only reason I can see to level up a dweller, is so that you can select and drag them around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to level them up. The higher the level, the higher their healthpoints.

This is important for two reasons:

1. Sending dwellers into the wasteland. Higher level dwellers will survive much longer with the same amount of stimpacks.
2. If disasters appear (Fire, Rad-Cockroaches or Raiders) your dwellers have a higher chance to survive without spending stimpacks on them.